# How to delay the new pod creating in a deployment when delete one pod?

Tags: deployment, kubectl

If a deployment set replica to 2, then we delete one pod using "kubectl delete pods" command, then the old pod will be in "terminating" status, and the new pod will turn out.

So, I hope the new pod will start to creat after the old pod has been terminated successfully, so, how should I do about it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [wait](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#wait) command:

> Wait for a specific condition on one or many resources.
>
> The command takes multiple resources and waits until the specified
>   condition is seen in the Status field of every given resource.
>
> **Alternatively, the command can wait for the given set of resources to be deleted by providing the "delete" keyword as the value to the
>   --for flag.**

Here is an aexample:

Wait for the pod "busybox1" to be deleted, with a timeout of 60s, after having issued the "delete" command:

```
kubectl delete pod/busybox1
kubectl wait --for=delete pod/busybox1 --timeout=60s
```

**---EDIT---**

**Depending on your use case the additional options would be to:**

- use [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) with "Ordered, graceful deployment and scaling."
- set replicas to 1, wait till the 2nd pod will be terminated and than set it back to 2
- use additional [deployment configuration](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#proportional-scaling) like `maxSurge` and `maxUnavailable`
- (less recommended) use `grace-period=0` with the `force` parameter but it may result in inconsistency or data loss and requires confirmation. More details [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#delete) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#force-deletion-of-pods).

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: Hello OhHiMark, thank you for your reply, sorry to see that even we use the wait command, the new pod will still turn out immediately. the wait command only wait the condition of the old pod, not the new pod, right?

Comment: In the given example: yes. Could you please check your stdout? Was the condition met successfully?